# Handle Missing Login/Log out Values in SQL Datetime

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, datetime, time

My Sql query:

```
CREATE TABLE TimeLog (
    [User] NVARCHAR(6),
    [Event] NVARCHAR(3),
    [Time] DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO TimeLog VALUES
(N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-04-15 00:31:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-04-16 20:10:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-04-21 14:59:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'OUT','2015-04-22 01:01:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-04-22 10:46:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'OUT','2015-04-23 00:58:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-04-23 14:50:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'OUT','2015-04-24 01:37:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'OUT','2015-04-25 01:01:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'OUT','2015-04-27 00:57:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-04-17 10:32:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-04-29 15:03:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'OUT','2015-05-01 00:44:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'OUT','2015-05-02 01:19:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-05-02 15:08:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'OUT','2015-05-03 01:08:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-05-03 15:06:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'OUT','2015-05-04 01:01:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-05-04 15:11:00'),
(N'Jibran',N'OUT','2015-05-05 01:08:00');

SELECT TOP (30) UserName, EventName, EventTime
From AttendanceEvents
Where UserName = 'Jibran'
```

Results in :

[image]

Is there a way to deal with Missing values for every IN value that doesn't have an OUT datetime value?

I've been reading an article : 
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/calculating-gaps-between-overlapping-time-intervals-in-sql/

But couldn't understand it half way through it.

How do I get Average of Datetime to use it for the missing values?

Expect Output would have OUT values for Every IN.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all: Please do not poste pictures. Try to set up a *stand.alone* scenario, best with a table definition and a fitting `INSERT` script. Nobod wants to type in your test data.

Comment: Secondly: I can imagine, how an `IN` entry is missing an `OUT` entry (application break down), but how do you explain `OUT`s without an `IN`? Is a user allowed to start the application multiple times with the same login? Is there any kind of `SessionId`?

Comment: These INs and OUTs are for time logging of Employees. The IN values without an OUT represent Employees who forgot to log out and vice versa which results in the data in such a format. @Shnugo

Comment: I understand, that a user forgets to log-out (in this case there is no corresponding `OUT`), but how can he forget to log-in? How do you explain three `OUT`-entries without an `IN`? If a user may log-in from three different machines and there is no SessionId, you are lost in any case...

Comment: Ahhh, I think I start to understand... This is not an application *login*, but an *I start to work* and a *Finished for today*... Correct? Try to set up some small set of sample data and provide the expected output (but please don't poste pcitures...)

Comment: "Expect Output would have OUT values for Every IN." What would be the EventTime of said OUT? Same goes for missing IN values - what would be the EventTime of these?

Comment: For example, If there is an IN value which is followed by another IN value, I would want an OUT value for the first IN, this OUT value would be the average of all the OUT values present in the table. @ZoharPeled

Comment: average out time for this sample data is 01:05:24. I'm guessing that's not such a good idea to use that. Also, calculating average time in SQL Server is somewhat tricky since AVG does not support the Time data type.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Right! I understand the approach of having 8 hour as average, but When I run the query at my end (Where the data is present as Datetime not as character) It gives me "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @ZoharPeled And If I want my final table to have INs and OUTs as Columns instead of Rows?

Comment: I have no conversions in my code at all. Also, the sample data you've posted contains datetime, not chars. Perhaps you got mixed up and it's chars at your end? Anyway, that's a different subject. unrelated to my answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Ahan! Got it right. But what about the Conversion of rows to columns?

Comment: Rows to columns is not that hard, but will take a couple of more ctes. [See here an online demo.](https://rextester.com/TOZO83770)

Comment: Why doesn't it show the complete output? For all instances that is. @ZoharPeled

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I have 26 rows returned from the final query in my answer, and 13 rows return on the new rextester link - each of them contains a couple of rows from the link in the asnwer - and as far as my math skills go, 13 * 2 = 26 - so I don't understand what is missing

Comment: Sorry I was doing something wrong! @ZoharPeled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution to add the missing rows to the table - both for missing `in` rows and for missing `out` rows.
The one thing I've done different than what you've asked is that the missing rows complete an 8 hour day with their source row.

Please note that this can only be used with a single user each time.

So here's how:

First, I've created a common table expression containing all the rows from the table that belongs to a specific user. In that cte I've used `lag` and `lead` to get the next event, the previous event and the next event time, and a row_number column.

Then I've used a union all of three queries based on that cte - one for original rows, one for new rows with `in` event, and one for new rows with `out` events.

The script is based on your sample data, and you can see an [online demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/LLSHEK12684)

```
DECLARE @User nvarchar(6) = N'Jibran';

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  [User],
            [Event],
            [Time],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Time]) + 0.0 As rn,
            LAG([Event]) OVER(ORDER BY [Time])  As PrevEvent,
            LEAD([Event]) OVER(ORDER BY [Time])  As NextEvent,
            LEAD([Time]) OVER(ORDER BY [Time]) As NextEventTime
    FROM TimeLog
    WHERE [User] = @User
)

SELECT  [User],
        'OUT' As [Event],
        DATEADD(HOUR, 8, [Time]) As [Time],
        rn + 0.5 As rn
FROM CTE
WHERE NextEvent = [Event]
AND [Event] = 'IN'

UNION ALL

SELECT  [User],
        'IN' As [Event],
        DATEADD(HOUR, -8, [NextEventTime]) As [Time],
        rn - 0.3 As rn
FROM CTE
WHERE PrevEvent = [Event]
AND [Event] = 'OUT'

UNION ALL
SELECT  [User],
        [Event],
        [Time],
        rn
FROM CTE

ORDER BY rn
```

Results:

```
User        Event   Time                    rn
Jibran      IN      15.04.2015 00:31:00     1,0
Jibran      OUT     15.04.2015 08:31:00     1,5
Jibran      IN      16.04.2015 20:10:00     2,0
Jibran      OUT     17.04.2015 04:10:00     2,5
Jibran      IN      17.04.2015 10:32:00     3,0
Jibran      OUT     17.04.2015 18:32:00     3,5
Jibran      IN      21.04.2015 14:59:00     4,0
Jibran      OUT     22.04.2015 01:01:00     5,0
Jibran      IN      22.04.2015 10:46:00     6,0
Jibran      OUT     23.04.2015 00:58:00     7,0
Jibran      IN      23.04.2015 14:50:00     8,0
Jibran      OUT     24.04.2015 01:37:00     9,0
Jibran      IN      26.04.2015 16:57:00     9,7
Jibran      OUT     25.04.2015 01:01:00     10,0
Jibran      IN      29.04.2015 07:03:00     10,7
Jibran      OUT     27.04.2015 00:57:00     11,0
Jibran      IN      29.04.2015 15:03:00     12,0
Jibran      OUT     01.05.2015 00:44:00     13,0
Jibran      IN      02.05.2015 07:08:00     13,7
Jibran      OUT     02.05.2015 01:19:00     14,0
Jibran      IN      02.05.2015 15:08:00     15,0
Jibran      OUT     03.05.2015 01:08:00     16,0
Jibran      IN      03.05.2015 15:06:00     17,0
Jibran      OUT     04.05.2015 01:01:00     18,0
Jibran      IN      04.05.2015 15:11:00     19,0
Jibran      OUT     05.05.2015 01:08:00     20,0
```

Side Note: You can tell which row was added by which part of the union all query based in the rn.

### Update

Following our conversation in the comments of the question - 
To get the ins and outs in different columns I've wrapped the union all query in another cte, and staked one more cte on top of that to get bigint row number.
Then it was just a matter of conditional aggregation with a twist - pairing even and odd row numbers into groups using cross apply.

Here is the full script - and of course, [an online demo](https://rextester.com/TOZO83770):

```
DECLARE @User nvarchar(6) = N'Jibran';

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  [User],
            [Event],
            [Time],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Time]) + 0.0 As rn,
            LAG([Event]) OVER(ORDER BY [Time])  As PrevEvent,
            LEAD([Event]) OVER(ORDER BY [Time])  As NextEvent,
            LEAD([Time]) OVER(ORDER BY [Time]) As NextEventTime
    FROM TimeLog
    WHERE [User] = @User
), CTERows AS
(
    -- Added out rows
    SELECT  [User],
            'OUT' As [Event],
            DATEADD(HOUR, 8, [Time]) As [Time],
            rn + 0.5 As rn
    FROM CTE
    WHERE NextEvent = [Event]
    AND [Event] = 'IN'

    UNION ALL

    -- Added in rows
    SELECT  [User],
            'IN' As [Event],
            DATEADD(HOUR, -8, [NextEventTime]) As [Time],
            rn - 0.3 As rn
    FROM CTE
    WHERE PrevEvent = [Event]
    AND [Event] = 'OUT'

    UNION ALL

    -- Existing rows
    SELECT  [User],
            [Event],
            [Time],
            rn
    FROM CTE
), CTEIntNumberedRows AS
(
    SELECT  [User],
            [Event],
            [Time],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rn) As rn
    FROM CteRows
)

SELECT  [User],
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Event] = 'IN' THEN [Time] END) As 'IN',
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Event] = 'OUT' THEN [Time] END) As 'OUT',
        Pairs
FROM CTEIntNumberedRows
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 0 THEN rn-1 ELSE rn END As Pairs
) x
GROUP BY [User], Pairs
ORDER BY Pairs
```